# How to make ::before/::after element clickable in css?

Tags: html, css, angular, pseudo-class

I tried to add box-shadow to rows in my table using ::after, because in Internet Explorer there are many bugs with box-shadow in tables, so this is my one solution when shadow display fine. I have data in rows and it has to be clickable and should make it possible to select text.

SCSS:

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 3px;
    padding: 0 2px;
    border-radius: 30px;

    &-row {
        position: relative;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
        border: 1px solid $c-white;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background-color: $c-white;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 7px 10px red;

        &::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            border-radius: 3px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 48px;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
            left: 0;
          }

    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="source">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table-header-cell"></th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="table-cell button"></td>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

I tried with `z-index:` but there is no result.

Is any method to make my rows clickable and such that I can select text from them??

Comment: just add width and height for before and after. pls give valuable code

Comment: Can you describe it more?

Comment: can you post the corresponding html to your css? Currently there is no `table-row` in your HTML.

Comment: As you can see in `<td>`  there is in `*matCellDef=let row`, so I think this is `table-row` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try this

**css**

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 3px;
    padding: 0 2px;
    border-radius: 30px;

    &-row {
        position: relative;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
        border: 1px solid $c-white;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background-color: $c-white;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 7px 10px red;

        &::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            border-radius: 3px;
            width: 48px;
            height: 48px;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
            left: 0;
            z-index:999;
          }

    }
}
```

Comment: pls share any fiddle to check your output dude

Comment: I don't understand what you mean of `fiddle`, if you can explain it more

Comment: pls share your code here and i need see your output https://jsfiddle.net/